# Configure default permission for Laravel `storage` directory for _newly_ created files

Tags: laravel, file-permissions

**How do I configure Laravel such that *newly created* files and directories below `./storage` become group writable?**

The Laravel `./storage` directory contains files which are dynamically generated during runtime of the application. For example, `./storage/framework/views` contains compiled and cached versions of the Laravel Blade templates. The webserver runs as user and group `apache:apache`. Upon every upgrade of the application, I need to run the console command `./artisan optimize:clear` to remove outdated, cached files. The admin user is also a member of the group apache, e.g. lets assume the account is `my_user:apache`.

Unfortunately, Laravel creates new files with permission `0640` and directories with permission `0750`, i.e. they are only group-readable, but not group-writable. This means running `./artisan optimize:clear` as `my_user` fails because group membership is not sufficient.

Comment: maybe this thread fix your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/11545457 and https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-framework-file-permission-security?reply=3193

Comment: Can you implement some kind of ACL (Access Control List) logic on your `storage` directory? These will cause files/folders in the specific folder to be created with a default set of permissions. Implementation differs between systems (windows, linux, mac, etc.), but I've had success with this in the past.

Comment: @Sumitkumar No these do not fix the problem. I highlighted the term _newly created_ on purpose, because that is the important part. Of course I know that I can do a `chmod` after the fact and make the file group writable later, but that is not what I asked for.

Comment: @TimLewis If it was my own installation, I surely could use Posix ACLs. But I am actually one of the developers and people who use our application frequently run into that problem. This means our users follow best practices, have a setup as described above and then something fails. Of course, they blame us (as the developers) first, even if it is a problem of the framework. Using the Posix ACL approach would be too much to ask. We must also consider users which are on a shared hoster and cannot use ACLs. Hence, the Laravel framework should properly set the permissions right upfront.

Comment: is running the command as the apache user an option e.g. using `sudo -u apache php artisan optimize:clear` ?

Comment: @user2690527 Yup; totally fair points all around! I haven't worked with this kind of distributed system; mine have always been self-hosted on servers I could modify as required. Your users should be able to implement their own solution, like using the same user/group for the Web and CLI instances, or an ACL set-up, etc.; I personally don't know of a way to handle this aside from something hacky like a script/command to modify the permissions when these files are generated, or something similar. I'll keep an eye on this post, see if someone else finds a good solution. Best of luck!

Comment: @apokryfos Same answer as for TimLewis. **I** can do that, but many user will simply forget about it. Anything which requires manual caution will eventually fail.

Comment: Not sure I understand the concern. Do you mean other members of your team might not do this correctly? If so can you write some automation for deployment?